# Hibernate necessary JARs

Tags: hibernate

What are the necessary jars required for HIBERNATE? I'm using Eclipse Indigo and Tomcat7.
I am using the following JARs:

- antlr 2.7.6
- common-collection 3.1
- dom4j 1.6.1
- hibernate 3
- java assist 3.4 ga
- jta 1.1
- mysql-connector-java 5.1.6
- slf4j -api 1.5.6
- slf4j-simple 1.5.6

But i get the following error:

> Failed to create sessionFactory object.java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/commons/logging/LogFactory
>    5 Sep, 2012 11:24:35 AM com.sun.faces.lifecycle.InvokeApplicationPhase execute
>    WARNING: #{register.action}: java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
>    javax.faces.FacesException: #{register.action}: java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError

Comment: consider using [maven](http://maven.apache.org/) or the like...

Answer (score 0):

I don't see common logging in your list.  Why not believe the exception and keep adding JARs until they stop?

Answer (score 0):

The missing class 'org.apache.commons.logging.LogFactory' is in commons-logging.jar

Remember the lib/required/ directory from your hibernate package contains all the JARs Hibernate requires.

Comment: what are the remaining jars should be placed in web\lib?

Comment: What version of Hibernate are you using?

Comment: hibernate 3.Plz tell me all the supporting jars

Answer (score 0):

This is well explained in the [**Hibernate documentation**](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/4.1/quickstart/en-US/html/ch01.html#hibernate-gsg-setup-releaseBundle) :

> - The lib/required/ directory contains all the JARs Hibernate requires. 
>     All the jars in this directory must also be included in your
>     project's classpath.
> - The /lib/jpa/ directory contains the hibernate-entitymanager jar and     its dependencies beyond those in lib/required/. This defines
>     Hibernate support for JPA.
> - The lib/envers directory contains the hibernate-envers jar and its    dependencies beyond those in lib/required/
> - The lib/optional directory contains the jars needed for optional    features of Hibernate.